# Registering Patterns in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array.

```
array(97) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(1) [5]=> int(1) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(1) [8]=> int(1) [9]=> int(1) [10]=> int(0) [11]=> int(0) [12]=> int(1) [13]=> int(0) [14]=> int(0) [15]=> int(0) [16]=> int(1) [17]=> int(0) [18]=> int(1) [19]=> int(1) [20]=> int(1) [21]=> int(1) [22]=> int(0) [23]=> int(0) [24]=> int(0) [25]=> int(1) [26]=> int(1) [27]=> int(1) [28]=> int(1) [29]=> int(1) [30]=> int(1) [31]=> int(1) [32]=> int(1) [33]=> int(1) [34]=> int(0) [35]=> int(1) [36]=> int(1) [37]=> int(0) [38]=> int(0) [39]=> int(1) [40]=> int(0) [41]=> int(1) [42]=> int(0) [43]=> int(1) [44]=> int(1) [45]=> int(1) [46]=> int(1) [47]=> int(1) [48]=> int(1) [49]=> int(1) [50]=> int(1) [51]=> int(1) [52]=> int(1) [53]=> int(1) [54]=> int(1) [55]=> int(0) [56]=> int(1) [57]=> int(0) [58]=> int(1) [59]=> int(0) [60]=> int(1) [61]=> int(0) [62]=> int(1) [63]=> int(1) [64]=> int(0) [65]=> int(0) [66]=> int(0) [67]=> int(0) [68]=> int(1) [69]=> int(1) [70]=> int(0) [71]=> int(0) [72]=> int(0) [73]=> int(0) [74]=> int(0) [75]=> int(0) [76]=> int(0) [77]=> int(1) [78]=> int(0) [79]=> int(1) [80]=> int(0) [81]=> int(1) [82]=> int(0) [83]=> int(0) [84]=> int(0) [85]=> int(0) [86]=> int(1) [87]=> int(0) [88]=> int(1) [89]=> int(0) [90]=> int(1) [91]=> int(0) [92]=> int(0) [93]=> int(1) [94]=> int(1) [95]=> int(1) [96]=> int(1) }
```

Is there a way that we can parse this and return true if it sees a 1 0 1 0 1 0 next to each other?

Comment: So what you have tried to get that `true`?

Comment: First option that comes to mind is to implode and search for a string of `101010`

Comment: Took a look at uasort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not the most mathematically elegant option, but a simple solution is to use `implode` and `strpos`:

```
if (strpos(implode('', $array), '101010') !== false) {
  echo 'Yes!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as you put it not elegant but does the job